# What to do when an user's "java" environment variable is messed up?

Tags: java

Some users, when running a Java project of mine, will be unable to open it. When I tell them to use the command line to see the crash message with

```
java -jar myApp.jar
```

The message is most likely

> "java" is not a recognised command

Or something like that. I've realised that this is probably because, for some reason, their environment variable for "java" is messed up, and they actually can't run any JAR file.

I usually walk them through the process of resetting their variable. But, ideally, this should never happen. Is there a reasonable solution to this? The users HAVE Java - it is just that for whatever reason the environment variable is all wrong. Is there a way for my app to, perhaps, workaround this apparently common problem?

Comment: Which OS are you talking about?

Comment: Try giving the user the absolute path to the java program. The default install path is less likely to be changed.

Comment: @Henry: All occurrences were on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a vb script for starting up the java program. You can get the java executable path and make the vbs launch the java program. Refer to [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0642.html) for help with vb script.

Answer (score 1):

One option can be to install a Java JRE with your application.

You can provide an executable or startup script that uses the JRE you installed.

This also ensures that the user is using the JRE that you tested with.

Comment: +1 Bundling a JRE is the only easy, reliable way to make sure your program will run.  Ideally the user shouldn't even have to know that the software was written in Java, unless it's a webapp or applet.  With an appropriate launcher (executable or script), LAF, and polish, you can make your Java application work as seamlessly as a native application.